# Error when creating Python List Comprehension

Tags: python

I faced A syntax error while working on lists using list comprehensions .

**Syntax of List Comprehension**

> **[expression for item in list]**

[image]

I want to make the x = x + 2 if x in range (4,10)

```
l1 = [1, 3, 4, 6, 8] 
l2 = [x + 2 for x in l1 if x in (1, 2, 3) else x in (4,10)]
print(l1,l2)
```

this is my error

```
  File "/home/user/Desktop/Study_python/main.py", line 12
    l2 = [x + 1 for x in l1 if x in (1, 2, 3) else x in (4,10)]
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Paste the error message as plain text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; your posting must be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: The `if-else` you're writing is a ternary expression, you just need to reorder it to `val_if_true if condition else val_if_false`. See Barmar's answer for more detail.

Comment: @Barmar yes sir i edit it

Comment: @blorgon ty for comment . what if i want to write else if statement    l2 = [x + 1 if x in (1, 2, 3) else (x + 2 if x in (4, 5) else x + 3 for x in l1) ]

    print(l2)
    exit()

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohamed/Desktop/Study_python/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    l2 = [x + 1 if x in (1, 2, 3) else (x + 2 if x in (4, 5) else x + 3 for x in l1) ]
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: when i tried this     l2 = [x + 1 if x in (1, 2, 3) else (x + 2 if x in (4, 5) else x + 3 for x in l1) for x in l1]

Comment: [<generator object <listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x7f94df84ac10>]

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: You can chain ternary expressions together like this: `val if condition else other_val if other_condition else yet_another_val...`. You're getting an error because you've returned a generator if `x` isn't in `(1, 2, 3,)`. You only need a single `for` loop.

Comment: as you said ive done the rule u mentiond and it gave me error     l3=[x+1 if x in (1,2,3) else x+2 if x in (4, 5) else x+3 if x in (6,7) for x in l1]

Comment: File "/home/mohamed/Desktop/Study_python/main.py", line 13
    l3=[x+1 if x in (1,2,3) else x+2 if x in (4, 5) else x+3 if x in (6,7) for x in l1]
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax @blorgon

Comment: @Ahmed.AI see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `if` and `else` in the value part of the list comprehension, not the condition. The condition is used for selecting items in the original list to process, there's no `else` option there (either you process an element or you don't). In the value part, it's used as a conditional expression that lets you specify different results depending on a condition, and in this context `else` is required.

```
l2 = [x + 1 if x in (1, 2, 3) else x + 2 for x in l1]
```

Note also that `x in (4, 10)` is not testing a range -- it just tests if `x` is either `4` or `10`. You can use `x in range(4, 10)` to test a range.

Comment: Or `4 <= x <= 10`, which I think is slightly more efficient than creating a `range` object, since `in` will still have to perform both comparisons. Not that efficiency is a concern here, but depending on the reader the chained comparison may be more readable. Just thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: @blorgon Probably, but they're probably close. The `range` class has a `__contains__` method that essentially turns into that.

Answer (score 2):

Comment chain is getting too long. OP, the reason this isn't working is because you don't have a final `else` to finish this expression:

```py
l3=[x+1 if x in (1,2,3) else x+2 if x in (4, 5) else x+3 if x in (6,7) for x in l1]
```

You need to either say

```py
l3 = [(x + 1) if x in (1, 2, 3) else (x + 2) if x in (4, 5) else (x + 3) if x in (6, 7) else (x + 4) for x in l1]
```

OR:

```py
l3 = [(x + 1) if x in (1, 2, 3) else (x + 2) if x in (4, 5) else (x + 3) for x in l1]
```

The ternary expression ALWAYS requires an `else`, or a fallback value if all other conditions are not satisfied: `val1 if cond1 ELSE val2` or `val1 if cond1 else val2 if cond2 ELSE val3` and so on.

By the way this expression is getting too complicated to be in a comprehension anyway. I suggest using a standard accumulator pattern for something with this many branches.

Comment: ty vm, yes right ive test it worked well . does this comprehension technique make any difference in the run time comparing to the standard   accumulator pattern @blorgon

Comment: should i depend on this or the normal for loop better

Comment: also if i want to try to read images inside for loop i can do the same or i better in normal for loop